# How to print download percentage in same line in file

Tags: python, file, stdout, carriage-return

I want to print the download status in a single line, This is what i'm doing :

```
        with open(LOG_FILE, 'w') as sys.stdout:
        print("\r Downloaded {} of {} bytes {:.2f}%".format(bytes_so_far, total_size, percent), end='')
        if bytes_so_far >= total_size:
            print('\n')
```

If I write to `sys.stdout.write` then it's working, But the same is printing a new line if I write in a file.

Comment: You could [truncate](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/truncate.html) the file each time you write to it.

Comment: My guess is that you don't want to write these updates at all if you are writing to a file. I think that what you should be using is `sys.stdout.isatty()` and only write the updates if it returns `True`. If `False` you should only write once, when it is done. The drawback is that if you are writing to a file and breaking out of the download, you won't have any updates at all presented.